# RDS swap usage. How much swapping is ok to have

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I wanted to understand how I can decide if RDS instance is under-utilized.

I think swap space metric is a good indicator to decide if it is over-provisioned or under-provisioned, but what kind of threshold values should I look in Cloudwatch (in percentage maybe).

How much swapping is ok to have? considering small CPU usage

Answer (score 1):

Ideally no swapping, this normally means that memory has been completely utilised and will have some performance issues for the application(s) using it.

Comment: but swapping still going to happen in case of a write operation, also if CPU is underutilized would that affect performance?

Comment: Hi, if CPU is underutilized that should not cause performance issues for you, but does likely mean you're paying for more resource than you need

Comment: Yeah that what I wanted to understand, If CPU is underutilized(20% average) and I have say 5% memory swapped on average is that an indication I should downgrade instance type?

Comment: Hi, If resources are constantly low then yes it should be downgraded